# Map.On / Map.off MapboxGL JS

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I'm working on a map with Mapbox GL JS and I have some features. I put them in different buttons. I have one button which is used to get the distance between two points

Before clicking the button the feature is not available. When I click this button it starts working but then if I press again that feature can't be stopped

How can I stop it?

I'm calling my function with an `addEventListener` that seems to run only when it starts the functionality, not when I have to stop it. Here is the code:

```
var Dist = document.getElementById('tt');
Dist.addEventListener('click', mesure)

function mesure() {

var distanceContainer = document.getElementById('distance');

// GeoJSON object to hold our measurement features
var geojson = {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": []
};

// Used to draw a line between points
var linestring = {
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
        "type": "LineString",
        "coordinates": []
    }
};


map.addSource('geojson', {
    "type": "geojson",
    "data": geojson
});

// Add styles to the map
map.addLayer({
    id: 'measure-points',
    type: 'circle',
    source: 'geojson',
    paint: {
        'circle-radius': 5,
        'circle-color': '#000'
    },
    filter: ['in', '$type', 'Point']
});
map.addLayer({
    id: 'measure-lines',
    type: 'line',
    source: 'geojson',
    layout: {
        'line-cap': 'round',
        'line-join': 'round'
    },
    paint: {
        'line-color': '#000',
        'line-width': 2.5
    },
    filter: ['in', '$type', 'LineString']
});




map.on('click', function (e) {
    var features = map.queryRenderedFeatures(e.point, { layers: ['measure-points'] });

    // Remove the linestring from the group
    // So we can redraw it based on the points collection
    if (geojson.features.length > 1) geojson.features.pop();

    // Clear the Distance container to populate it with a new value
    distanceContainer.innerHTML = '';

    // If a feature was clicked, remove it from the map
    if (features.length) {
        var id = features[0].properties.id;
        geojson.features = geojson.features.filter(function (point) {
            return point.properties.id !== id;
        });
    } else {
        var point = {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    e.lngLat.lng,
                    e.lngLat.lat
                ]
            },
            "properties": {
                "id": String(new Date().getTime())
            }
        };

        geojson.features.push(point);
    }

    if (geojson.features.length > 1) {
        linestring.geometry.coordinates = geojson.features.map(function (point) {
            return point.geometry.coordinates;
        });

        geojson.features.push(linestring);

        // Populate the distanceContainer with total distance
        var value = document.createElement('pre');
        value.textContent = 'Total distance: ' + turf.lineDistance(linestring).toLocaleString() + 'km';
        distanceContainer.appendChild(value);
    }

    map.getSource('geojson').setData(geojson);
});

};
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: I tried to translate your question in a better english but the original post is not totally clear. You have the possibility to measure the distance on the map between two points, this is ok. It looks like you want to start and stop the distance feature with the same button [please correct me if I'm wrong]. Do you have also the problem that when you try to start the distance calculation the other features [associated to the same buttons] do not stop? I want to help you translating properly but let the community understand exactly what's your issue. Have a good day!

Comment: Yes it's totally that , When I click again on the button , the function on the addeventLister does not run